# How to choose coset leader between same-weight vectors?

Tags: coding-theory

Consider the code with following parity-check matrix
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&1\end{array} \right)
$$
Given the syndrome $s = 11$, what is the coset leader?

I was given this problem on a multiple choice test. Options included $1100$ and $0101$, but multiplication with check matrix results $11$ in both cases, so they both have the same syndrome. Since their weight is the same, how do we choose the coset leader? Correct answer was $1100$, but I'm not sure I understand why.

Comment: Could you provide the definition of coset leader?

Comment: @Lecter Given a code $C \subseteq \mathbb F_p^n$, a *coset leader*  of a coset $\overline y + C$ is a vector of minimum weight in $\overline y + C$.

Comment: As they have the same syndrome they both belong to the same coset of $C$. Since both have the same weight, the correct option has to be both (it's a multiple choice test, right?).

Comment: I chose the option "Not clear", but got 0 points, says the correct answer is 1100.

Comment: @Lois2B As Lecter mentioned, unless the code is perfect (which is not the case), both vectors are coset leaders... unless in another part of the test it was stated to work with a particular decoder. You see, decoding a linear code is the same as assigning to each vector a coset leader, and for each choice you have a different decoder, so either there is some information missing in this post (i.e. how we choose our decoder) or both answers are equally correct.

Comment: In any case, I'm sure the lecturer/professor would be more than happy to answer this question if you email him/her.